# Shared Preferences in another package

Tags: android

I am new to android development. Is there a way to extends class from another package? I am trying to get the shared preferences from another package, although I am able to access the shared preferences between classes within the same package. However, at different packages, I have no idea how I should do editer.commit() or edit the shared preferences that is in another package. Please help.

Comment: **Short answer,** impossible unless both the device and your app are rooted (Google simply does not allow).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this code

to put a string to sharedpreference

```
    SharedPreferences USERNAME_and_PASSWORD;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

USERNAME_and_PASSWORD = getSharedPreferences(Shared_preference_key,
                MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = USERNAME_and_PASSWORD.edit();
                editor.putString(user_name_key, userName);
                editor.commit();
```

to get a string from shared preference

```
    SharedPreferences USERNAME_and_PASSWORD;
 USERNAME_and_PASSWORD = getSharedPreferences(Shared_preference_key,
                    MODE_PRIVATE);
     USERNAME_and_PASSWORD = getSharedPreferences(Shared_preference_key,
                        MODE_PRIVATE);
    String Return_Password = USERNAME_and_PASSWORD.getString(pass_word_key,
                    "Guest");
```

Comment: These are for retrieving and editing the shared preferences within the same package, what I am trying to do is to access the sharedpreferences from classes that is in another package. For example, if I am getting the sharedpreferences using the code  "USERNAME_and_PASSWORD = getSharedPreferences(Shared_preference_key,
                    MODE_PRIVATE);" from another class that is in another package, it will not be able to detect the variable "Shared_preference_key" therefore it will not work. Is there a way that I can access from the sharedpreferences from another package?

Comment: we can acess it across diffrent package.add these lines before acessing shared prefernce  String Shared_preference_key = "Shared Preference";SharedPreferences USERNAME_and_PASSWORD;
USERNAME_and_PASSWORD = getSharedPreferences(Shared_preference_key,
                MODE_PRIVATE);String Return_Password = USERNAME_and_PASSWORD.getString(pass_word_key,
                "Guest");

Comment: This answer is clearly wrong! Does not solve at all the problem, even after editing. I wonder why it was accepted... It's also confusing because of the way identifiers are named. The first parameter for getSharedPreferences is a file name, not a key

Answer (score 0):

```
I put example for the sharing data between two Activities using shared preference.
Using this code u get idea of shared preference how it's work.
you can also be shared data between two activites which are in different packages in the same application.
```

```
PracSharePrefActivity Class
```

```
package com.sharedpref;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class PracSharePrefActivity extends Activity {

    private SharedPreferences settings;
    private String name,subject;
    private Button btnSave;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        name = settings.getString("Name","");
        subject = settings.getString("Subject", "");

        Log.e("Name0==",name);
        Log.e("Subject0==",subject);


        String yourName="Deval";
        String yourSubject="Android";

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

        editor.putString("Name",yourName);
        editor.putString("Subject", yourSubject);

        editor.commit();

        Log.e("Name 1==",settings.getString("Name", ""));
        Log.e("Subject 1==",settings.getString("Subject", ""));       


        btnSave=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(PracSharePrefActivity.this,GetSharedPref.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }



}
```

```
"GetSharedPref" Class
```

```
package com.sharedpref;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class GetSharedPref extends Activity {
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private String name,subject;
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.pref);          

            preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            name = preferences.getString("Name", "");
            subject=preferences.getString("Subject", "");

            Log.e("Name:  ",preferences.getString("Name", ""));
            Log.e("Subject:  ",preferences.getString("Subject",""));

            preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);    
     }
}
```

Comment: using "getsharedpref" class u get the shared preference data and "pracshareprefactivity" class set the data.